# Making a beamer page that includes an array. Code included

Tags: beamer, arrays

Please help with code below.  Firstly, `beamer` seems to insist that every line within the array code requires its own begin and end `$` signs.  Then, 
though I've checked this for hours, it insists that the `\frame{  closing 
parentheses`}`needs another`$` which it won't take.  Any thoughts?
Thanks VERY much.  :)  Frank
This is my first time using your service, and I see that that printout that follows my typing this does not reproduce the code correctly,  e.g, it does not show double backslashed where I have them.  I'm stumped.

```
\frame{
\frametitle{... and the ``solution vectors'' are the cols of ${\bf q}_{16}{\bf VertexMat}\; =$}
$ \left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}$
$  .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732 $\\
$   0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732$\\
$  .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0$\\
$   0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803$\\
$   0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732$\\
$  .0366     &    0    & .0366    &     0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0$\\
$   0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    &     0    & .0366    & 0$\\
$  .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0$\\
$  .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0$\\
$   0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0$\\
$  .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0$\\
$   0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732$\\
$   0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803$\\
$  .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0$\\
$   0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732$\\
$  .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732$
$\end{array}\right)$ \\ 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This code contains a bunch of errors. You're trying to use a matrix as frame title. This is possible, most likely, but does not look really nice

Comment: There's the `pmatrix` environment (package `amsmath`) that is meant for typesetting a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of errors in here. In my opinion, the `frame` environment is more failsafe. The matrix shouldn't be typeset in the frametitle and `pmatrix` should be used as well. The alignment of the figures is difficult, of course.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{A title}
\small
%frametitle{... and the ``solution vectors'' are the cols of ${\bf q}_{16}{\bf VertexMat}\; =$} % Don't understand this????
$\begin{pmatrix}
  .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732 \\
  0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732\\
  .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0\\
  0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803\\
  0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732\\
  .0366     &    0    & .0366    &     0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0\\
  0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    &     0    & .0366    & 0\\
  .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0\\
  .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0\\
  0    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0\\
  .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0\\
  0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732\\
  0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803\\
  .0366    & 0    & .0366    & 0    & 0    & 0    & .0366    & 0\\
  0    & .0732    & .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732\\
  .3902    & .2803    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732    & 0    & .0732
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```